# Subject verb agreement in Number?

Tags: british-english, subcontinental-english

In the sentence " The Hospitality of the Villagers is to be learnt by all" Why "is" used as verb. why not "are" ? is subject used in this sentence is plural or singular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The **Hospitality"** is **the singular subject**, qualified by the prepositional phrase ***"of the Villagers."*** Therefore, **the singular verb "is"** is appropriately used. If you turn the sentence around, you would say, **"All villagers *are* expected to learn to be hospitable."** Is the difference between these two examples clear?

Comment: Yeah, It's too clear.

Comment: @SriramP- I sincerely apologize if I have offended you. I'm sorry. Sometimes in reading and writing it is hard to determine what another person already knows and intends by his question. Please suggest how I can edit my response to be better or more polite. Thank you.

Comment: No your answer is clear and polite. I miss understood this sentence. Thank you for answering to my question.

Comment: @Sriram: You should expect a certain amount of "disdain" if you ask questions like this on ELU. That's what we have [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) for.

Comment: @SriramP- Thank you for your kind comment and reassurance. And FumbleFingers, I **almost always** respect your answers and comments, but I believe there is **no place on EL&U** where it is appropriate to express **"disdain"** towards anyone asking a sincere question!